# How to build a FastCGI module with Rad Studio?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, datasnap

For stability reasons, I would need to convert my current ISAPI DataSnap application to FastCGI. ISAPI only uses one process and multiple threads, FastCGI uses a process from a process pool for each session. The server provides PDF reports and other time consuming resources. Using a dedicated process for each session would be more stable.

The problem is that Rad Studio / DataSnap only provides CGI and ISAPI but not FastCGI.
Is there a way or library to built a FastCGI module? I use C++ in Rad Studio, so I could use C++ libraries although I would prefer a native Rad Studio solution. The server would be Microsoft IIS.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/extpascal/WnvAzDS2mks and https://www.google.nl/search?q=fastcgi+delphi&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=AyKGV_KYJsqX-Aaqwo-gAw

Comment: I'm not sure that you'll have a more stable setup of you chose to use FastCGI instead of ISAPI on IIS. With Application Pools in IIS, you have exactly a set of dedicated processes to handle a number of sessions with. Optionally with recycling configurations to fine-tune to your needs.